# Stress-strain relation in spherical coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems, elasticity, stress-strain

Hey so I have a timeless question but I didn't find a source to check it.
Would you have a precise reference (or if you can write it that's also perfect for me) for the stress strain relation in linear-elasticity in spherical coordinates please ?

I mean in general you can write :

$$\sigma_{ij}=K u_{kk}\delta_{ij}+2\mu(u_{ij}-\frac{1}{3}u_{kk}\delta_{ij}) $$
with $u_{ij}=\frac{1}{2}(\partial_i u_j +\partial_j u_i )$ with $\mathbf{u}$ the strain and $\mathbf{\sigma}$ the stress. 
This is in cartesian coordinates, isn't it ? with $i,j,k \in \{x,y,z\}$. How does it change in the spherical coordinates ? I mean $u_{xx}+u_{yy}+u_{zz}=u_{rr}+u_{\theta\theta}+u_{\phi\phi}$ since the trace doesn't change with the system of coordinates. So is it right to write the same relation with $i,j,k \in \{r,\theta,\phi\}$ ? I mean is the only change the actual expression of the strain ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the version of the stress-strain relation you're familiar with in Cartesian coordinates?  There are a few different conventions & parameterizations out there.

Comment: The stress-strain relation is a tensor equation, so it looks the same in all coordinates. What is different is the formula for the components of the strain in non-cartesian coordinates. This  is more complicated. The (infinitessimal) strain   is given  1/2 the Lie derivative of the metric with respect to the displacement field

Comment: So I added something to complete the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_elasticity